# Why doesn’t this integration method work?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Taking dy/dt = xy

Of course you can divide y from both sides getting a logarithmic function, but why can’t you integrate both sides with dt and get the right answer? Or what is wrong with this example?

Ex: ∫(dy/dt)dt=∫(xy)dt

The dt cancel out so ∫dy=xy∫dt

y=xyt divide both sides by y

1=xt

Comment: From what you have written it is certain that $y$ is a function of $t$ so at least $\int xy\,dt = y\int x\,dt$ is invalid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You know that $y$ (and probably $x$) is a function of $t$ so the step
$$
\int xy\,dt = y\int x\,dt
$$
is not valid.